# Eclipse MAT: remote jvm monitoring

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jvm, jmx, eclipse-memory-analyzer

Is it possible, using that eclipse plugin, to remote connect to a running jvm (jmx enabled) as I would do with jConsole or jProfiler, for monitoring and debugging heap, threads and so on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not according to this thread:

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/565234/

> MAT can only trigger heap dumps from processes on the same box where
> the tool is running. Triggering dumps on a remote machine is not
> possible. Internally we also call jmap to get the dumps.